# Does Copper reacts with Sodium Sulfate solution?

Tags: electrochemistry

Okay I am trying to make a capacitor in which current collector is copper foil and electrolyte is sodium sulfate. Would this work? Do these two react with each other or not?

Comment: If you can provide more information, that will help us help you get an answer to your question. You could expand on the experimental setup, for instance, and what capacitance you expect, and so on. What are the other materials in the cell?

Comment: Why, these two are perfectly indifferent to each other. Your capacitor should be fine, as long as you don't apply any voltage to it.

Comment: Ofcourse one must charge and discharge capacitor. Its like psuedocapacitor nano  material is deposited on the copper plate which acts as current collector.

Comment: To expand on Ivan's answer, this would not be a good idea. I assume you mean to use a solution of sodium sulphate in water, which has neutral pH. While this is not itself corrosive to copper (copper being far less reactive than sodium) it will however corrode badly at the positive electrode due to anodic dissolution. Copper can however be used safely as a negative electrode current collector.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to make an [**electrolytic capacitor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolytic_capacitor), you've picked inappropriate materials.

An electrolytic capacitor works because a material such as aluminum or tantalum develops a tightly-adherent insulating oxide layer when immersed in certain solutions and "formed". Copper does not have an adherent insulating oxide; instead, cuprous oxide is a semiconductor and [$\ce{Cu2O}$ can be used to make a rectifier](http://www.hpfriedrichs.com/radioroom/cu-diode/rr-cu-diode.htm).

You can [make your own aluminum electrolytic capacitor](http://rimstar.org/science_electronics_projects/make_electrolytic_capacitor.htm) with common household chemicals.

Comment: Well its a kind of super capacitor using Psuedo and double layer capacitance. Its oxide and graphene based actually. So would aluminim foil work if I place my active materials onto it?

Comment: There are directi0ns for making your own ultracapacitor (AKA supercapacitor) at http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-Graphene-Supercapacitor/ and http://arstechnica.com/science/2012/03/a-supercapacitor-in-your-optical-drive-dvd-rw-used-to-burn-graphene-capacitors/. Not sure what you mean "using Psuedo", though.

Answer (score 0):

use copper sulphate.
if you charge it,  it forms microfacets, via the copper moving from the + to collect on the -,  mix it with glue, wait for it to dry to form the dielectric separator, but dont break the chains you have to be gentle with it.